# Override `spring.cloud.config.profile` at runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I'm using Spring cloud config, and I need to override my `spring.cloud.config.profile` property at runtime to either be `blue` or `green`

I have a method - `determineConfigProfile()` that returns `blue` or `green` but how to do I tell Spring Boot to run this method before fetching the config (i.e. resolving the config properties) and how do I tell Spring Boot to override the system property?

I see here https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_client.html that `"profile" = ${spring.profiles.active} (actually Environment.getActiveProfiles())` but I don't see how to set the active profiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving this because I think it's useful, what I did was in my `public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer`:

I did the following:

```
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        String profile = determineConfigProfile();
        System.setProperty("spring.cloud.config.profile", profile);
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
```

This runs before the Spring cloud config kicks off and it overrides the profile.

Comment: Rather than setting the value as a system property, you might consider setting the property through `SpringApplicationBuilder.properties()`. `properties()` sets the value in a lower-priority property source, so it'd be easier to override the property if you had a need to.

Comment: `determineConfigProfile()` *is the overriding* value, or I want it to be the canonical value, regardless of anything else...